# How Design Dialog value will be stored for Multi Language website

Tags: aem

I have two Page P1 in English and P2 in Spanish created with same template T1. I have made some changes in P1 and P2 separately via design dialog. How will the value be stored under etc/design node?

Answer (score 1):

Design dialog changes are per template and not per page. Therefore, in your case the allowed/disallowed components will be stored under /etc/design for the template. The normal path for design properties is `etc/design/.../jcr:content` according to your template name.

In your case, making changes from P1 and later changing from P2 will override any changes made from P1.

This is by design for AEM.

Comment: So, I have added some text in P1 - English page and then without doing any rollout, then change some text in P2- Spanish page. So it will override the P1 page changes and only P2 page changes will be present at the end at etc/design/.../jcr:content node.

Comment: Rollout is not related to design mode changes.

Comment: Hi Prajwal, you need to specify more details about this scenario and AEM version. Are you using [design dialog from Classic UI](http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/create-design-dialog-in-aem/), [Design Dialog from Touch UI](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/author/page-authoring/default-components/core-components.html) or [Design Mode dialog](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/author/page-authoring/default-components/designmode.html) for defining components allowance on given page/template. in case if you mean the first case, please check my post.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you have modified value in *Design Dialog* of some of the component which instances are present on P1 and P2 pages, and these pages are created with the same template T1.

There are three main conditions that make the component properties values that are present in *Design Dialog* of component instance available for other component instances on other pages:

- they need to use the same template

And as I see this condition is fulfilled for you.

- the pages need to use the same designs

The path to designs is defined by `cq:designPath` property, which can be defined in `jcr:property` node the template itself, it might be inherited from one of the Parent Pages or set manually in *Page Properties* the page. If P1 and P2 are based on the same template and you need to use different values for them for different languages, then you need to use different *cq:designPath* for each language page.

The last condition:

- the component instance needs to be at the same content position on both pages

It just simply means that if the component on one page is used in a different section than on the other, then the properties are not shared so that it would be good if the other page would be a copy, Live Copy or reference the structure of the first one in a different way.

And finally, answering your question about localization of storing this value, it can be found properly under:

```
<cq:designPath>/jcr:content/<templateName>/<path-to-your-component-on-page>
```

so that if your `cq:designPath` is `/etc/designs/siteA`, template name is `homepage`, and the component `logo` is created on the first parsys `par` on the page, then the path to *Design Dialog* properties values looks like this:

`/etc/designs/siteA/jcr:content/homepage/par/logo`

As you can see the path depends on these three elements. It is also possible that value for *cq:designPath* is missing or cannot be determined for the page at all, in that case, the data should be saved under *default* designs node:

`/etc/designs/default/jcr:content/homepage/par/logo`